# Implement a loop logic within an rxjs pipe

Tags: rxjs

I have a class, **QueueManager**, which manages some queues.

QueueManager offers 3 APIs

- `deleteQueue(queueName: string): Observable<void>`
- `createQueue(queueName: string): Observable<string>`
- `listQueues(): Observable<string>`: Observable`

`deleteQueue` is a fire-and-forget API, in the sense that it does not return any signal when it has completed its work and deleted the queue. At the same time `createQueue` fails if a queue with the same name already exists.

`listQueues()` returns the names of the queues managed by **QueueManager**.

I need to create a piece of logic which deletes a queue and recreates it. So my idea is to do something like

- call the `deleteQueue(queueName)` method
- start a loop calling the `listQueues` method until the result returned shows that `queueName` is not there any more
- call `createQueue(queueName)`

I do not think I can use `retry` or `repeat` operators since they resubscribe to the source, which in this case would mean to issue the `deleteQueue` command more than once, which is something I need to avoid.

So what I have thought to do is something like

```
deleteQueue(queueName).pipe(
  map(() => [queueName]),
  expand(queuesToDelete => {
    return listQueues().pipe(delay(100))  // 100 ms of delay between checks
  }),
  filter(queues => !queues.includes(queueName)),
  first() // to close the stream when the queue to cancel is not present any more in the list
)
```

This logic seems actually to work, but looks to me a bit clumsy. Is there a more elegant way to address this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The line `map(() => [queueName])` is needed because `expand` also emits values from its source observable, but I don't think that's obvious from just looking at it.

You *can* use `repeat`, you just need to subscribe to the `listQueues` observable, rather than `deleteQueue`.

I've also put the delay *before* `listQueues`, otherwise you're waiting to emit a value that's already returned from the API.

```js
const { timer, concat, operators } = rxjs; 
const { tap, delay, filter, first, mapTo, concatMap, repeat } = operators;

const queueName = 'A';
const deleteQueue = (queueName) => timer(100);
const listQueues = () => concat(
  timer(1000).pipe(mapTo(['A', 'B'])),
  timer(1000).pipe(mapTo(['A', 'B'])),
  timer(1000).pipe(mapTo(['B'])),
);

const source = deleteQueue(queueName).pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('queue deleted')),
  concatMap(() =>
    timer(100).pipe(
      concatMap(listQueues),
      tap(queues => console.log('queues', queues)),
      repeat(),
      filter(queues => !queues.includes(queueName)),
      first()
    )
  )
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log('next', x), e => console.error(e), () => console.log('complete'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.4/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```